# Import Spring's OpenApi file in AWS Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-api-gateway, openapi

1. I am able to download OpenApi 3.0 json file using http://localhost:9999/v3/api-docs.
2. Then I have replaced URL to below:

   "servers": [
   {
   "url": "http://IP_ADDRESS_OF_AWS_EC2:9999",
   "description": "Generated server url"
   }
   ]
3. Then replaced all "*/*" content type to "application/json".
4. Imported final JSON file in to AWS Gateway, and able to see all the APIs.
5. However, I then need to go to each API and edit it by selecting "HTTP", see below, it is empty. Can you please share what I am missing, I thought it should be pre-populated as there are 45 APIs. Please guide.
   [image]

Comment: AWS-specific config can be specified by using [`x-amazon-apigateway-*`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html) extensions in your OpenAPI file.

Comment: This works, thank you!